# Python - split dataframes that are contained within a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I am extracting tables from a PDF and the page can have more than 1 table. I am using the Tika library for extraction. In this case, the output is 2 data frames (so the 2 tables) contained within a list - please could someone share how I can extract each dataframe out?

For context each df has 2 columns and the same number of rows.

Example:

```
[0   data1  
1    data2
2    data3  
3    data4

0   data10
1   data12
2   data13
3   data14 ]
```

I want to extract the first df here so:

```
0    data1  
1    data2
2    data3  
3    data4
```

I have tried to parse like this:

```
df[:3] or df[-1]
```

Please could someone share where I am going wrong?

Comment: IIUC: A `list` or `dict` is the appropriate way to store multiple DataFrames. Otherwise, you will manually need to instantiate each DataFrame to a variable (e.g. `df1 = my_list_of_dataframes[0]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to index into the list if it is a list. Double check the types and the hierarchy of how the data is stored. Without you showing the error, it's hard to tell what your problem is. However, you can do this for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['gg', 'bb'], 'h': ['ttt', 'sdf']})

list_of_dfs = [df, df]

# get the first dataframe:
list_of_dfs[0]

# If you are trying to combine them into one table (assuming they are of the same form):
df_all = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
df1 = df.head(4)
```

will get the first 4 items